# Iterating through a custom double linked list

Tags: c++, list, data-structures

I am implementing a double linked list. I have implemented functions for adding to the head and tail of the list. I have been trying to make a function that would print all the elements of a given object.
Though the function prints the first value it does not print any other item in the list.

> d_list.h

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include "node.h"

 #ifndef NODE_H
 #define NODE_H


template<class T>
class d_list{
   private:
       int l_size;
       Node<T>* head;
       Node<T>* tail;

   public:
       d_list():l_size(0){
          head=nullptr;
          tail=nullptr;
       }
       Node<T>* gethead(){return this->head;}
       Node<T>* gettail(){return this->tail;}

         int getlength(){
           return this->l_size;
         }

       void addashead(T data){
          Node<T>* curr_node=new Node<T>(data);
          if(this->head==nullptr){
            this->head=curr_node;
            this->tail=curr_node;
            this->l_size=l_size+1;
          }else {
             curr_node->next=this->head->previous;
              this->head->previous=curr_node;
             this->head=curr_node;

              this->l_size=l_size+1;
          }
       }

       void addastail(T data ){
          Node<T>* curr_node=new Node<T>(data);
          if(this->tail==this->head){
            this->head->next=curr_node->previous;
            curr_node->previous=this->head;
            this->tail=curr_node;
            this->tail->next=nullptr;
            this->l_size=l_size+1;
          }
          else{
            this->tail->next=curr_node;
            curr_node->previous=this->tail;
            this->tail=curr_node;
            this->l_size=l_size+1;
          }
       }

       Node<T>* begin(){
         return this->head;
       }

       Node<T>* end(){
         return this->tail;
       }

       bool isempty(){
         return this->head==nullptr;
       }

       T& back(){
         return this->tail->m_data;
       }

       T& front(){
         return this->head->m_data;
       }

       void printlist(){
           Node<T>* temp= this->head;
        while(temp) {
        std::cout << temp->m_data<< " -> ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }


       }

};

#endif
```

> node.h

```
template <class T>
class Node{
    private:


    public:
       T m_data;
       Node<T>* next;
       Node<T>* previous;
        Node()=default;
        Node(T data){
           m_data=data;
           previous=nullptr;
           next=nullptr;
        }
       ~Node();


};
```

> main.cpp

```
#include "d_list.h"

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;



int main(){

    d_list<int> d1;


    d1.addashead(50);



    d1.addastail(20);


    d1.addastail(60);



    d1.addastail(80);



    d1.printlist();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some mistakes in your addastail() and addashead() method.

I removed these mistakes,Check this:

```
 void addashead(T data){
          Node<T>* curr_node=new Node<T>(data);
          if(this->head==nullptr){
            this->head=curr_node;
            this->tail=curr_node;
            this->l_size=l_size+1;
          }else {
             curr_node->next=this->head;
              this->head->previous=curr_node;
             this->head=curr_node;
             this->l_size=l_size+1;
           }

   }
```

In the first line of else part,
you wrote:

```
curr_node->next=this->head->previous;
```

But it should be: `curr_node->next=this->head;`

As curr_node's next should point on head,not head's previous.

```
void addastail(T data ){
          Node<T>* curr_node=new Node<T>(data);
          if(this->tail==this->head){
            this->head->next=curr_node;
            curr_node->previous=this->head;
            this->tail=curr_node;
            this->tail->next=nullptr;
            this->l_size=l_size+1;
          }
          else{
            this->tail->next=curr_node;
            curr_node->previous=this->tail;
            this->tail=curr_node;
            this->l_size=l_size+1;
          }
       }
```

In the first line of if part,you wrote:

```
this->head->next=curr_node->previous;
```

But it should be:`this->head->next=curr_node;`

Comment: Yeah it works! Thank you. How are we achieving a bidirectional connection though?

Comment: Yeah i get in now! Thank you Well explained 

Comment: let there are two nodes A and B,for bidirectional connection b/w A and B, A 's next should point on node B, and B's previous should point on A. Hence,now you can traverse from node A to node B by A=A->next and  from B to A by B=B->previous.